# Add custom class to form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Having such form

```
<%= form_tag 'search', method: 'get', class: 'form-horizontal' do %>
     <%= label_tag  :search, 'Enter url here' %>
     <%= text_field_tag :search  %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Get it!' %>
    <% end %>
```

Code above adds `class='form-horizontal'` for `form` tag.

How can I add `class='form-control'` for each input field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
text_field_tag :search, nil, class: 'form-control'
```

> For future reference:

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})

text_field_tag :search
# => <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />

text_field_tag :search, 'Enter your search query here'
# => <input id="search" name="search" type="text" value="Enter your search query here" />

text_field_tag :search, nil, class: 'form-control'
# => <input class="form-control" id="search" name="search" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= form_tag 'search', method: 'get', class: 'form-horizontal' do %>
   <%= label_tag  :search, 'Enter url here' %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, {:class => 'form-control'}  %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Get it!' %>
<% end %>
```