# adding a class to a text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, form-helpers

I am trying to give a class to my text_field_tag

I have this

```
<%= text_field_tag :login_aei, class: 'form-control' %>
```

but it keeps generating this :

```
<input type="text" name="login_aei" id="login_aei" value="{:class=>&quot;form-control&quot;}">
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: please check following link.may be it will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198495/add-custom-class-to-form-fields

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You declared it wrong. Here is the one will work.

```
<%= text_field_tag :login_aei, "", class: 'form-control' %>
```

I gave the value of the `input` field as empty string, but you can give any value what meets your business needs.

Comment: Works prefectly

Answer (score 2):

In the case of data binding is needed,

```
<%= text_field_tag(:personName,"#{@person.name}", class:'form-control', placeholder: 'User Name' )%>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text_field_tag` is an ActionView method. First thing to do is [check the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag). It says, `text_field_tag` takes this form:

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

Additionally:

1. `value` is the initial value for the text box. Notice the default is nil, not an empty string. By passing in a string, you are using it in an undocumented way, which may have worked in this instance but could behave subtly different.
2. `name` is a string. While Rails *currently* converts a symbols into strings here, consider using a string instead of a symbol for better future-proofing.
3. The two issues above were overlooked by skipping straight to SO for the quick answer. Consider RTFM as it is the only definitive source, besides the source code itself.